# Before reapair wiring - may Skoda Superb (2010) have an door impact sensor?

Tags: wiring, sensor, door, skoda

I have ab broken door wiring harness in my Skoda Superb (2010; 8004-AIT; **German version**). I think about to repair it myself. But I'm not shure if the Skoda has an door impact sensor. In this case I would'nt do it.

All I found in the door is this door controller (8x0 959 793 c).

[image: The door contoller]

[image: The broken wiring]

**Question:**

- May this Skoda have an door impact sensor?
- How can I check it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm almost sure that the **Superb has an door impact sensor**:

Starting the engine without connected door wiring leads to an **"airbag fault"** error.

**Since there is no airbag in the door, this must be caused by the missing connection to a door impact sensor.**

So I decided not to repair the wiring but to replace it.

Comment: VAG tends to mark these sensors, in my car the impact sensor in the door was red/yellow. So if you have the door card off, it should be easy to spot.